# Python 3.x: Trying to compare current element with previous and next (without built-in functions)

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, integer, compare

I'm trying to write code that adds to a count if the current list element is greater than both the previous list element *and* the next list element. So, for example, in a list: [1, 3, 5, 7, 2]... 1 and 2 are not evaluated because they only have one number to the side. So 3 is the first to be compared and 3 is not greater than 1 *and* 5, 5 is not greater than 3 *and* 7, and 7 *is* greater than 5 and 2 so count = 1.

This is for homework so I can't use built-in functions. List is of random length and may contain positive and negative numbers.

I tried two variations...
In this version, the i value never goes up. Why is this? How do I get it to go to the next number?

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
b = a[0]
count = 0

for i in a[1:]:
    for j in a[2:]:
        if i > j and i > b:
            count +=1
        b = i

print(count)
```

In the second version, I get Index Error: list index out of range. How can I fix such an error?

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
prev = nxt = 0
b = a[1]
count = 0

for i in range(1, len(a)):
    prev = a[i-1]
    nxt = a[i+1]
    if b > prev and b > nxt:
        count +=1
    prev = b
    b = nxt

print(count)
```

Thank you for any help. I would like to know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: In the second version, the Index error happen I think when `i = len(a)-1` and you take `nxt = a[i+1]` which is then out of the range of `a` indices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code you have written you are trying to access the index which is not on the list.You are trying to access the next element for the last element in the list, which is not there! 
Just change the for loop range

```
for i in range(1,len(a)-1)
```

Here is the code I have written:

```
 count = 0
 for i in range(1,len(a)-1):
     if a[i+1] < a[i] > a[i-1] :
          count += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check without the first and last:

```
my_list = my_list[1:-1]
res=0
for ndx,el in enumerate(my_list):
  if my_list[ndx-1] > el and my_list[ndx+1] > el:
    res+=el
```

Comment: This is useful! Thank you for your help.